# the console window in the popen module is not working properly

Tags: python, windows, console, popen

I am using the popen module to open a console window in which I call a program while passing two arguments and then I retrieve the answer on the same console window.
What I tried to do is redirecting the stdout and the stderr of popen to a file and then reading the file and taking this result to a text zone in my GUI.
The  problem is that the console window is always popping out but empty and the result doesn't show in my text unless I close the console window.
I tried adding a startupinfo but that didn't work, and I tried changing the '-k' in popen to '-c' (see in code below) and it didnt work either. any help ?

```
def call_interpreter():
    que2.put_nowait(queue[0])
    b=que2.get(block=True)
    a=que1.get(block=True)
    print "prameters are :" ,a ,b ,"\r\n"
    c='python C:\\workspace\\Project_Interpreter\\Tool-v1.0.py -s %s %s'%(b,a)
    startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
    startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
    ps=sp.Popen(['cmd','/C',c] , creationflags=0, startupinfo=startupinfo, stdout=PIPE, stderr=sp.STDOUT, stdin=PIPE)
    texte01= ps.stdout.readlines()
    print(str(texte01))
    with open('logggg.txt','w') as txt:
        txt.write(str(texte01) + '  ' )
    chaine = "PASSED" # Texte à rechercher
    fichier = open("logggg.txt","r")
    for ligne in fichier:
        if chaine in ligne:
            tr=('congratulations your test has passed !!!')
        else :
            tr=('Sorry your test has failed !!!')
        zone_texte.insert(END,tr)
```